# SSP Personal Features for Everyone

Tags: administration, forms-authentication

How may I grant Everyone Use Personal Features access to our SSP, we are not using AD to authenticate users, so NT Authority\Authenticated Users will not work in this situation. I want to enable My Links for everyone that has access to our site.

Comment: What are you using for authentication to your site?  Local user accounts?  Anonymous access (I'm guessing not)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have a forms based authentication and the SSP cannot currently see that the users or groups that have access exist. Would we have to attach our authentication to the SSP to enable Personalization?

Comment: Amanda, I'm sorry I didn't see your comment yesterday.  Yes, you would need to also configure the SSP for forms based authentication.  Here is the TechNet article that explains it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262201(office.12).aspx.  [As a side note, I was so happy to see the SSP's go away in SharePoint 2010].  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not allowing anonymous access since you want to use the personalization features such as My Links.  I would suggest that whatever user store you are using for authentication (be it local user accounts, SQL Server Provider or LDAP) should support groups as well as users. You may just have to make it part of your user registration process to add the users to a global group to accomplish this.